# How could I join 2 class link by many to many relation on symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, join, many-to-many

My problem is that apparently, I'm doing a bad join between two class for a query. My goal is to select the name of a teacher and his Module that he teachs.

Here is the many to many join in my Teacher class :

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module", inversedBy="idProfesseur")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="enseigne",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ID_PROFESSEUR", referencedColumnName="ID_PROFESSEUR")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ID_MODULE", referencedColumnName="ID_MODULE")
 *   }
 * )
 */
 private $idModule;
```

Here is the many to many join in my Module class:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Professeur", mappedBy="idModule")
 */
private $idProfesseur;
```

Here the last query that i tried:

```
public function findAllClasses()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT p.nom, m.nomModule
            FROM AppBundle:Professeur p, AppBundle:Module m 
            WHERE p.idProfesseur = m.idModule
            AND p.idProfesseur = 1
            ')
        ->getResult();
}
```

It returns me an empty result. 
So, my question : how could I do the join?

To precise, I did this on mysql workbench and it works:

```
SELECT p.nom, m.NOM_MODULE FROM PROFESSEUR p, ENSEIGNE e, MODULE m WHERE p.ID_PROFESSEUR = e.ID_PROFESSEUR AND e.ID_MODULE = m.ID_MODULE AND p.ID_PROFESSEUR = 16
```

Comment: all modules of professor are stored in $idModule property of Professor entity. just get list of professors, then get modules for every Professor. I hope that you remember that it is array of modules for each Professor.